# Classification accuracy of a Random Multi-label Classifier

Tags: multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, accuracy

What is the exact **accuracy of a random classifier** which has n labels (say 1000) where k labels (say 50) are true? 
Can I say the accuracy of a random classifier has an upper bound of k/n?

-Edit-

I am interested in a numerical figure or an upper bound for a random classifier (for example the accuracy of a classifier randomly picking 50 classes out of 1000 where some 50 classes are correct). 
Sorry if my previous question is not fully understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you want accuracy as @AlexanderRoiatchki defined it (see also [CV.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12702/232706)), and want exactly $k$ distinct labels, both true and predicted.

Letting $X$ denote the random variable of the number of correct labels for an instance, we have that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X=x) = \binom{k}{x} \binom{n-k}{k-x} / \binom{n}{k} $$
(choose the correct labels and the incorrect ones separately).  The accuracy score from a given instance is 
$$ \frac{|T_i \cap P_i| }{ |T_i \cup P_i| } =  \frac{ X}{2k-X}. $$

So the expected value of the accuracy is
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{2k-X}\right] = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} \sum_{x=0}^k \frac {x \binom{k}{x} \binom{n-k}{k-x}} {2k-x}.$$
That doesn't seem to have a nice closed form.  When $k\ll \sqrt{n}$, this seems to be roughly $k/2n$, but I've made a big assumption about the non-dominating terms of the summation being negligible.

In the specific case you mentioned, $k=50, n=1000$, I get 0.0259.

---

Edit, in response to comment: if you want to define accuracy as just $X/k$, then the expected accuracy of the random classifier simplifies nicely to $k/n$:

$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} \sum_{x=0}^k \frac{x}{k} \binom{k}{x} \binom{n-k}{k-x}
&= \frac{1}{k\binom{n}{k}} \left( k \binom{n-1}{k-1} \right) & \text{combinatorial identity*} \\
&= \frac{ (n-1)! / [(k-1)! (n-k)!] }{ n! / [k! (n-k)!] } & \text{just expand coefficients}\\
&= \frac{k}{n} & \text{simplify factorials}
\end{align*}
$$

(* I can't help but elaborate.  In the current context, this is the number of choices with $X=x$ with the additional decoration of a special correct label (one of the $x$).  To get the RHS then, pick the decorated label first ($k$), then choose the remaining labels without regard to how many are correct ($\binom{n-1}{k-1}$). )

Comment: Thanks a lot @ben :D
I am taking the accuracy as X/ k as I always select top 50 probable values. Anyway got the answer to the question, thanks a lot again :D

Comment: the expected value should be divided by the nCk, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Wenuka, thanks, of course I missed the nCk; I'll edit it in.  Also, with accuracy defined as just X/k things do simplify nicely, so I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a multi-label classifier (that is, having potentially more than one label per data point) we can have a prediction which is either *fully correct*, *partially correct* or *fully incorrect*. To account for this, the following accuracy metric has been proposed:
$$\text{Accuracy} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|T_i \cap P_i|}{|T_i\cup P_i|},$$
where $n$ is the sample size, $|\cdot|$ denotes the number of elements of a set, $T_i$ is the set of true labels and $P_i$ is the set of predicted labels for an item of the sample.

For instance, let's say the $i$-th item has actual labels $A, B, C$ and $D$ (that is $T_i = \{A, B, C, D\}$, but your classifier predicts labels $B, D$ and $E$ (that is $P_i =\{B, D, E\}$), then you'd get
$$\frac{|T_i\cap P_i|}{|T_i\cup P_i|}=\frac{|\{B,D\}|}{|\{A,B,C,D,E\}|}=\frac{2}{5}.$$
To get the accuracy for the entire training set, you calculate this for each instance $i=1,\dots, n$ and you average it out.

You can also have a look at the evaluation metrics section of the article in Wikipedia about multi-label classifiers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification#Statistics_and_evaluation_metrics

Comment: Thank you @alexander :D However can you help me with "how to obtain a numerical figure" or at least an upper bound for a "random classifier" (a classifier just randomly picking classes)?